# Trouble getting my basic switch program to execute

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm a beginner programmer, and I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  It's just a simple program that lets the user input one of three types of weather, and depending what is entered into the text field, the program will answer with the appropriate type of footwear.  I have been poring over it for hours, tweaking here and there, but I can't get it to work.  Any ideas?  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>What Shoes Should I Wear?</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function shoeWeather() {
            var shoe;
            switch (weather) {
                case 'hot':
                    shoe = "sandals";
                    break;
                case 'rain':
                    shoe = "galoshes";
                    break;
                case 'snow':
                    shoe = "boots";
                    break;
                default:
                    shoe = "shoes";
                    break;
                return;
                document.getElementById('shoe').innerHTML = shoes;
            }
        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    Weather:<input type="text" id="weather">
    <button type="button" onclick="shoeWeather()">What's the Right Shoe for the Job?</button>
    <div id="shoe"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the variable `weather`, that you are trying to operate your switch statement on, isn't defined. You will have to read the value of your input and then operate the switch on that.
2. you are putting your `document.getElementById('shoe').innerHTML = shoes;` inside the switch, before a return statement and use a mistyped variable (shoes should be shoe).

Try something like this:

try:

```
var shoe='';
switch (document.getElementById('weather').value){
     //set shoe based on switch cases
}

document.getElementById('shoe').innerHTML = shoe;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I'm not sure what you mean by setting shoe based on switch cases. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ChrisBazzle just exactly what you did before inside the switch up until the return statement. it's where you set the shoe variable to the values based on the case.